# Interaction with deployed contract over private blockchain Error: invalid address

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, abi

I have deployed a smart contract over my private ethereum blockchain using geth.

Smart Contract

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.6.0;

contract GreenPoints {

    string public name;
    string public symbol;
    uint8 public decimals = 18;
    uint256 public totalSupply;

    mapping (address => bool) public frozenAccount;
    mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;

    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
    event FrozenFunds(address target, bool frozen);
    event Burn(address indexed from, uint256 value);

    constructor(
        uint256 initialSupply,
        string memory tokenName,
        string memory tokenSymbol
    ) public {
        totalSupply = initialSupply * 10 ** uint256(decimals);  
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = totalSupply;                
        name = tokenName;                                   
        symbol = tokenSymbol;                               
    }

    function _transfer(address _from, address _to, uint _value) internal {
        require(_to != address(0x0));
        require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value);
        require(balanceOf[_to] + _value >= balanceOf[_to]);
        uint previousBalances = balanceOf[_from] + balanceOf[_to];
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;
        emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        assert(balanceOf[_from] + balanceOf[_to] == previousBalances);
    }

    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(!frozenAccount[_to]);                           
        require (balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value);                

        _transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {       
        require (_to != address(0x0));                          
        require (balanceOf[_from] >= _value);                   
        require (balanceOf[_to] + _value >= balanceOf[_to]);    
        require(!frozenAccount[_from]);                         
        require(!frozenAccount[_to]);                           

        _transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function burn(uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value);   
        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;            
        totalSupply -= _value;                      
        emit Burn(msg.sender, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function burnFrom(address _from, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value);                
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;                         
        totalSupply -= _value;                              
        emit Burn(_from, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function freezeAccount(address target, bool freeze) public {
        frozenAccount[target] = freeze;
        emit FrozenFunds(target, freeze);
    }
}
```

This is how i have initialized variables on geth console.

```
var abi=[ { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "name", "outputs": [ { "name": "", "type": "string" } ], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "totalSupply", "outputs": [ { "name": "", "type": "uint256" } ], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [ { "name": "_from", "type": "address" }, { "name": "_to", "type": "address" }, { "name": "_value", "type": "uint256" } ], "name": "transferFrom", "outputs": [ { "name": "success", "type": "bool" } ], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "decimals", "outputs": [ { "name": "", "type": "uint8" } ], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [ { "name": "_value", "type": "uint256" } ], "name": "burn", "outputs": [ { "name": "success", "type": "bool" } ], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [ { "name": "", "type": "address" } ], "name": "balanceOf", "outputs": [ { "name": "", "type": "uint256" } ], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [ { "name": "_from", "type": "address" }, { "name": "_value", "type": "uint256" } ], "name": "burnFrom", "outputs": [ { "name": "success", "type": "bool" } ], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "symbol", "outputs": [ { "name": "", "type": "string" } ], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [ { "name": "_to", "type": "address" }, { "name": "_value", "type": "uint256" } ], "name": "transfer", "outputs": [ { "name": "success", "type": "bool" } ], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [ { "name": "", "type": "address" } ], "name": "frozenAccount", "outputs": [ { "name": "", "type": "bool" } ], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "constant": false, "inputs": [ { "name": "target", "type": "address" }, { "name": "freeze", "type": "bool" } ], "name": "freezeAccount", "outputs": [], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [ { "name": "initialSupply", "type": "uint256" }, { "name": "tokenName", "type": "string" }, { "name": "tokenSymbol", "type": "string" } ], "payable": false, "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "constructor" }, { "anonymous": false, "inputs": [ { "indexed": true, "name": "from", "type": "address" }, { "indexed": true, "name": "to", "type": "address" }, { "indexed": false, "name": "value", "type": "uint256" } ], "name": "Transfer", "type": "event" }, { "anonymous": false, "inputs": [ { "indexed": false, "name": "target", "type": "address" }, { "indexed": false, "name": "frozen", "type": "bool" } ], "name": "FrozenFunds", "type": "event" }, { "anonymous": false, "inputs": [ { "indexed": true, "name": "from", "type": "address" }, { "indexed": false, "name": "value", "type": "uint256" } ], "name": "Burn", "type": "event" } ];

var contract=web3.eth.contract(abi);

var contractinstance=contract.at('0x6621b0431ed6f533575380f2ba4788f44b5049b6')
```

I am able to check balance of address by using `contractinstance.balanceOf('0x029285ee26b9da62f138133a9fe40cb8c2219c82')`

But i am unable to utilize **transferFrom** function of my contract

It results in following error

```
contractinstance.transferFrom('0x029285ee26b9da62f138133a9fe40cb8c2219c82', '0xe149cb26b99f176367e32c4ce33bc3bcb455cec6', '100')
Error: invalid address
    at web3.js:3930:15
    at web3.js:3756:20
    at web3.js:5025:28
    at map (<native code>)
    at web3.js:5024:12
    at web3.js:5050:18
    at web3.js:5075:23
    at web3.js:4137:16
    at apply (<native code>)
    at web3.js:4223:16
```

Although wallets do exist

```
 personal.listWallets
[{
    accounts: [{
        address: "0x029285ee26b9da62f138133a9fe40cb8c2219c82",
        url: "keystore:///home/lubuntu/Project/data/keystore/UTC--2019-02-20T06-42-47.223857724Z--029285ee26b9da62f138133a9fe40cb8c2219c82"
    }],
    status: "Unlocked",
    url: "keystore:///home/lubuntu/Project/data/keystore/UTC--2019-02-20T06-42-47.223857724Z--029285ee26b9da62f138133a9fe40cb8c2219c82"
}, {
    accounts: [{
        address: "0xe149cb26b99f176367e32c4ce33bc3bcb455cec6",
        url: "keystore:///home/lubuntu/Project/data/keystore/UTC--2019-02-20T06-43-46.766062805Z--e149cb26b99f176367e32c4ce33bc3bcb455cec6"
    }],
    status: "Locked",
    url: "keystore:///home/lubuntu/Project/data/keystore/UTC--2019-02-20T06-43-46.766062805Z--e149cb26b99f176367e32c4ce33bc3bcb455cec6"
}]
```

I am trying to transfer tokens from my main account to another account that was created before deploying contract over my private blockchain.

Comment: Which version of web3 are you using?

Comment: Also, `contractinstance.transferFrom(...)` should continue with `.send({from: someApprovedAccount})`.

Comment: @goodvibration I am using web3 1.0, i have tried it with .send, but still the same error is produced.

Comment: Are you sure? `contractinstance.transferFrom` should be `undefined` in that case (you should use `contractinstance.methods.transferFrom`). Can you please run `npm ls web3` and say what you're getting?

Comment: I am getting web3@1.0.0-beta.46 and also in geth it shows  modules: admin:1.0 clique:1.0 debug:1.0 eth:1.0 miner:1.0 net:1.0 personal:1.0 rpc:1.0 txpool:1.0 web3:1.0
When i run contractinstance.methods.transferFrom, it produces following TypeError: Cannot access member 'transferFrom' of undefined

Comment: That's very weird. I'm pretty sure that on v34 you need to use `methods`. Maybe they've changed it between then and v46, but I doubt it, because that would be an API-breaking change. In any case, to begin with, on web3.js v1.x, you need to use `new web3.eth.Contract` instead of `web3.eth.contract`. I'll write this as an answer, but I'm guessing that you may have a few additional problems on top of that.

Comment: Is it right to test it using geth console? Because even on  var contractInstance = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, '0x6621b0431ed6f533575380f2ba4788f44b5049b6'); it produces following TypeError: 'Contract' is not a function

Comment: It proves (once again) that you are working with web3 v0.x!

Comment: You are absolutely right, geth is using web3 api: "0.20.1". I executed web3.version and it printed 0.20.1. I need to upgrade its api somehow

Comment: You don't have to though. web3.js v0.20 should be fine.

Comment: Oh okay. I was using right commands then but why is error still persisting then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked after resetting default account with

```
web3.eth.defaultAccount = eth.accounts[0]
```

And then

```
myContractInstance.transferFrom("0x029285ee26b9da62f138133a9fe40cb8c2219c82","0xe149cb26b99f176367e32c4ce33bc3bcb455cec6","10000",{from: eth.accounts[0]})
```

works fine.